# Play image sequence in C#

Tags: c#, image

What is the best way that uses less CPU has better performance for player a sequence of images in C#?

I'm writing an application for an industrial touch panel wince 5. The images are a maximum of 100kb each. Unfortunately I have to use C# because this is a form that must be integrated into an existing application.

Comment: Please give more details: what you mean by "playing sequence of images"? Custom animation? Do you have example to share?

Comment: How big will the images be? Scientific images, panoramic or some professional hi-def images can be over a gigabyte. You need very different approach in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating into a C# application does not mean you have to use C# - you can write code in C++ or other languages and use p/invoke to call it from C#. But unless you're doing something really inefficient in C# you can get pretty decent performance out of it (I work on what is essentially a flight simulator written in C#, and it's pretty high performance - not as high as we could achieve with C++, but still a perfectly viable/realistic alternative, and it's so much faster to develop).

However, unless you are writing a realtime app for a very low-spec CPU and it's already struggling to keep up with its tasks, loading and displaying a 100kB image at any likely framerate shouldn't be much of a problem.

As you don't really specify the bounds of what you can do, it's hard to give a precise answer.

In general, it would make sense to use DirectX/OpenGL in preference to GDI in preference to GDI+ to get decent rendering/blitting performance.

If you have control over it, then there are many file formats that you can use which will help the speed (by compressing the data well to minimise the amount of data to be loaded, and/or by using hardware decompression approaches, better data streaming and caching approaches, pre-processing to optimise the image data to suit the target hardware, etc). If you have this much flexibility you may be able to use a video playback library or even an external video playback application that will do all the work for you, leaving you to write a trivial bit of "control logic" in C#. This will get you a much more efficient system than you are likely to achieve by rolling your own solution.